# Testing Node.js server and Flash socket

Tags: node.js, sockets, flash

I'm trying to establish socket connexion between a Node.js server and a Flash (Flex) application. I have some unexpected results that I can't explain by myself.

Here are my code.

Flex :

```
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       creationComplete="windowedapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">


    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import com.pnwrain.flashsocket.FlashSocket;
            import com.worlize.websocket.WebSocket;

            import mx.events.FlexEvent;


            private var _flashSocket:FlashSocket;
            private var _webSocket:WebSocket;
            private var _xmlSocket:XMLSocket;

            protected function windowedapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                    _xmlSocket = new XMLSocket();
                    _xmlSocket.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, function():void{trace('close')});
                    _xmlSocket.addEventListener(DataEvent.DATA, onData);
                    _xmlSocket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, function():void{trace('connect');});
                    _xmlSocket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, function():void{trace('io error')});
                    _xmlSocket.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, function():void{trace('sec error')});
                    _xmlSocket.connect("127.0.0.1", 8888);              

            }

            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                _xmlSocket.send("client test");
            }

            protected function onData(event:DataEvent):void
            {
                trace(event.data);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:VGroup>
        <s:TextInput id="ti" />
        <s:Button label="test" click="button1_clickHandler(event)" />
    </s:VGroup>


</s:WindowedApplication>
```

My simple Node.js server :

```
const net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) 
{
    socket.on("data", function(message){        
        socket.write(message + "\n");
    });

    socket.on("connect", function(){            // Never triggered
        console.log("connected to client\n");
    });

    socket.on("drain", function(){              // Never triggered
        console.log("drain !\n");
    });

    socket.on("close", function(){              
        socket = undefined;
    });

    setInterval(function(){ 
        if(socket)
        {
            socket.write("test\n");
        }       
    }, 5000);   

}).listen(8888, "127.0.0.1");
```

So when I click on my Flex button, data is sending from my app to my server and from my server to my app so it seems to be good.

When I waiting for 5 seconds my Flex does not receive "test" String as expected but when I click on my app button after 1 minute or less I receive data like this :

```
test  
test  
test  
test  
.....  
client test
```

It seems that my server doing some "retention of information" but I can explain why or why some events are never triggered as it should be (?).

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm just finding solution after posting (it's always the case no ?)

I have to use `\0` in message.

```
socket.write("test\0");
```

NOT

```
socket.write("test\n");
```